# Open some Windows dialogs directly

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt, shortcut

From my software I'd like to be able to access several Windows dialogs direcly. Basically shortcuts to some dialogs that I use from time to time and that are otherwise difficult to access.

One example would be the "Merge or delete network locations" dialog ([screenshot](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Media/0000244/00001.jpg)).

Using Process Explorer I found out the following information about that dialog:

```
C:\Windows\System32\netprof.dll
C:\Windows\system32\DllHost.exe /Processid:{44C39C96-0167-478F-B68D-783294A2545D}
```

Unfortunately I can't figure out what to do with it.
For other dialogs/locations there are ways like this:

```
Trash:
%windir%\explorer.exe /n,::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}
Keyboard:
%systemroot%\system32\control.exe /name Microsoft.RegionalAndLanguageOptions /page /p:"keyboard"
```

But I can't figure out a general way to do this.

The programming language doesn't matter in this case. You're welcome to post a solution in any language or by the command prompt. Please use the mentioned dialog as an example, but I hope to find out a general solution. Thanks.

Comment: Useful related items here http://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-command-line-commands-on-windows

Comment: There's no general solution, there are any number of different ways the myriad dialogs that are used by standard Windows components could be launched. Some may have no practical way of launching outside of the component that uses them. The particular dialog you mention looks like it's running in a COM server. You could launch the server relatively easily but that may not result in the dialog being displayed. There's no general way to ask a COM server to show a particular dialog, and this particular COM server may not provide any means to tell it to show the dialog you want.

Comment: "There's no general way to ask a COM server to show a particular dialog" - Why not? If a link in another Windows dialog can launch it, why can't my program do the same? That particular dialog does not depend on any parameters from the previous dialog(s). It's stand-alone. There must be a way to find out how it's launched originally and replicate that action!?

Comment: There's no API for it. They're internal, designed to be called by the operating system, not by your program. This is fundamentally equivalent to me asking how to make my application open dialogs from *your* application!

Answer (score 0):

Not every dialog can be programmatically accessed as you suggest.  Some dialogs are custom to the application that launches them, so you won't be able to easily access them.

I wasn't able to find a reference to the "Merge or delete network locations" dialog that you were primarily interested in.

For the ones that can be accessed, there are basically two types.

1. Dialogs that can be invoked from the regular Windows command line.  [As mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310248/open-some-windows-dialogs-directly#comment39509303_25310248) by kenny in the comments, this [serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/q/3780/118874) captures a lot of the known commands.
2. Another approach would be to launch the dialog through powershell. Powershell can access and launch the .NET framework dialogs.  [This TechNet Scripting Guys](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/09/01/hey-scripting-guy-september-1.aspx) article provides an example of launching the open file dialog through powershell.

The article is well worth reading, but this is the snippet that does the magic.

```bsh
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{  
     [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") |  Out-Null

 $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
 $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
 $OpenFileDialog.filter = "All files (*.*)| *.*"
 $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
 $OpenFileDialog.filename
} #end function Get-FileName

# *** Entry Point to Script ***

Get-FileName -initialDirectory "c:\fso"
```

And just in case you wanted something besides the open file dialog, you would change the following line to the dialog you need.  `$OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog`

Comment: While your answer shows a way to programmatically open a dialog it's limited to the dialogs in System.Windows.Forms.* which isn't quite useful in my case. I was very confident that there's a way to open a specific form of which I know the dll and its GUID. All the replies so far indicate that this is not possible. However, if there's one thing I learned as a developer then that there's no "impossible" in coding, some things are just a little bit more complicated, maybe even "hackish", but never impossible.

Comment: I came here searching for how to quickly open the latest dialog possible from the list of: "Audio Balance Levels" < "Level" in "Speakers Properties" < "Playback" in "Sound" 
as one of my speakers in laptop sounds dilapidated, and the balance is reset whenever the system volume is set to zero (which is frequent accidental happening due to win 10 3-finger gestures).

yes, i agree with never absolutely impossible. but yes when you consider time, efforts, and availability constraints. MS-Win is a closed OS... so, niche things like these are not covered anywhere (easily visible) on the net.